# Loading large images by using JavaScript pairing with media queries

Tags: javascript, media-queries

I've been looking at PPK's article [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/08/combining_media.html) as, perhaps, a more efficient way of loading the proper images when using media queries.  The main way that he suggests loading them is pairing JS with CSS.  So the code would look like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
// styles go here for screen widths less than 900px wide
}

if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 900) {
// script to load the images goes here for screen widths less than 900px wide
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is, what's the best way to load the images?  Is it the old skool way of using new Image() or is appending stuff with jQuery the way to go?  Is there one that's less of a server strain than the other?

Thanx in advannce...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server strain? Either way you are delivering image data, and there aren't a whole lot of ways to do that.  You simply make a request for each image and the server responds.  Best you can do is make sure the images are being served with proper `Cache-Control` headers.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  alert('woot');
};
img.src = url;
```

It's simple, easy to do in a loop, and can handle callbacks when they are done.

Comment: Hi Squeegy.  Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, it's greatly appreciated.
Yes, Cache-Control headers are key here so I'll make sure that's working properly
Just so I'm clear: if the image that I'm loading is called 'pic.gi'f, the final JS code would look like this?

if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 900) {
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  alert('woot');
};
img.src = 'pic.gif';
} 
Thanks again!

Comment: Yep.  Make the image, bind a function to onload (if you want to know when it loads), then set the `src` property of the image object.  That's all you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I really appreciate your taking the time.  Will do this, then append the content with jQuery.